# Morphism of schemes with non-sober image

Tags: gn.general-topology, schemes

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Can the image of $f$ endowed with the subspace topology not be sober?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a disjoint union of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb F_p$ over primes $p$ and consider the obvious map $X\to\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$. The image $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z\setminus\{(0)\}$ is not sober.

Comment: can this happen if both source and target are integral schemes of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Which scheme do you mean? As a space, the disjoint union of the $\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb F}_p$ is discrete. It is the underlying space of which scheme? But it is not e. g. $\operatorname{Spec}$ of the product of all ${\mathbb F}_p$, is it? Because not seeing what is $X$ I do not see why $(0)$ is not in the image.

Comment: This scheme is not a spectrum of any ring (since it's not quasicompact), if that's what you are talking about. I honestly don't know how to describe this scheme any better than just as a disjoint union of ringed topological spaces.

Comment: @Wojowu You can describe it as the open subscheme of $\mathrm{Spec}(\prod_p\mathbb{F}_p)$ whose complement is defined by the ideal  $\bigoplus_p\mathbb{F}_p$. I do think your definition is better!

Comment: @schematic_boi In the case of $\mathbb{C}$-schemes of finite type, *assuming* that $f$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-morphism, I suggest you use Chevalley's theorem that the image of $f$ is constructible.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly but is a non-locally closed constructible subset of a Noetherian sober space necessarily sober? Do you have some reference for that?

Comment: @schematic_boi Your question would be more appropriate for math.stackexchange so this is a welcoming present: you easily reduce to observing that if a space is noetherian, irreducible, and a finite union of finitely many irreducible locally closed subspaces, then one of them must be dense, hence open.